# SVN compatibility issues in AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, tortoisesvn

Are there any compatibility issues for SVN in AWS EC2 ?

It is because I am trying to list the objects which are present in my repository in EC2 with this command:

```
svn list https://svn.companyname.net/svn/abc-de-fgh-lm/.
```

but we get an error :

> Error Code:
>   svn: E170013
>   svn: E130005

However if I try to list the objects in an another physical unix server, we are able to access the objects.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There is nothing specific about Amazon EC2 that should be impacting you. Try updating your libraries (eg `sudo yum update` and for any apps you use) to match versions with the system that is functioning.

Comment: You should check the server logs and take a closer look at the errors that you receive. The server or network is either misconfigured on the side of the server, or there is a problem with the SVN client that you use. E.g. you may be entering an invalid URL to the server and the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any compatibility issues for SVN in AWS EC2 ?

No.

Note that it is not possible to help without knowing all the details about your SVN installation. Version, configuration, reproduction script etc.